# Entity Framework Query is too slow

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have to put a complex query on your database. But the query ends at 8000 ms. Do I do something wrong? I use .net 1.1 and Entity Framework core 1.1.2 version.

```
var fol = _context.UserRelations
                  .Where(u => u.FollowerId == id && u.State == true)
                  .Select(p => p.FollowingId)
                  .ToArray();

var Votes = await _context.Votes
                          .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationDate)
                          .Skip(pageSize * pageIndex)
                          .Take(pageSize)
                          .Where(fo => fol.Contains(fo.UserId))
                          .Select(vote => new
                {
                    Id = vote.Id,
                    VoteQuestions = vote.VoteQuestions,
                    VoteImages = _context.VoteMedias.Where(m => m.VoteId == vote.Id)
                        .Select(k => k.MediaUrl.ToString()),

                    Options =  _context.VoteOptions.Where(m => m.VoteId == vote.Id).Select( ques => new
                    {
                        OptionsID = ques.Id,
                        OptionsName =  ques.VoteOption,
                        OptionsCount =  ques.VoteRating.Count(cout => cout.VoteOptionsId == ques.Id),
                    }),
                    User = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == vote.UserId).Select(usr => new
                    {
                        Id = usr.Id,
                        Name = usr.UserProperties.Where(o => o.UserId == vote.UserId).Select(l => l.Name.ToString())
                            .First(),
                        Surname = usr.UserProperties.Where(o => o.UserId == vote.UserId)
                            .Select(l => l.SurName.ToString()).First(),
                        ProfileImage = usr.UserProfileImages.Where(h => h.UserId == vote.UserId && h.State == true)
                            .Select(n => n.ImageUrl.ToString()).First()
                    }),
                    NextPage = nextPage
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Do you have one or more relevant index in your database ? (you should be able to see the SQL request in the output window of VS, you can then run this request in SQL Server Managment Studio and see the actual execution plan)

Comment: My database schema. http://prntscr.com/hx6btm

Comment: At first glance it looks a bit chatty

Comment: No wonder it's slow. Do you even understand what you are doing there? For every single vote you are performing 3 queries. So if you have 1000 votes, you will do 3000 (!!!!) queries to your database. How do you expect that to be fast? You should **think** about the data you want to fetch and use EF Cores [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) to get most of this data in few queries

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the SQL queries you generate to the server (and results of this queries). For SQL Server the best option is SQL Server Profiler, there are ways for other servers too.

- you create two queries. First creates `fol` array and then you pass it into the second query using Contains. Do you know how this works? You probably generate query with as many parameters as many items you have in the array. It is neither pretty or efficient. It is not necessary here, merge it into the main query and you would have only one parameter.
- you do paginating before filtering, is this really the way it should work? Also have a look at other ways of paginating based on filtering by ids rather than simple skipping.
- you do too much side queries in one query. When you query three sublists of 100 items each, you do not get 300 rows. To get it in one query you create join and get actually 100*100*100 = 1000000 rows. Unless you are sure the frameworks can split it into multiple queries (probably can not), you should query the sublists in separate queries. This would be probably the main performance problem you have.
- please use singular to name tables, not plural
- for performance analysis, indexes structure and execution plan are vital information and you can not really say much without them

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you are potentially executing 100, 1000 or 10000 queries. For every `Vote` in your database that matches the first result you do 3 other queries.

For 1000 votes which result from the first query you need to do 3000 other queries to fetch the data. That's insane!

You have to use EF Cores [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) feature to fetch this data with very few queries. If your models are designed well with [relations and navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) its easy.

When you load flat models without a projection (using `.Select`), you have to use `.Include` to tell EF Which other related entities it should load.

```
// Assuming your navigation property is called VoteMedia
await _context.Votes.
    .Include(vote => vote.VoteMedia)
    ...
```

This would load all `VoteMedia` objects with the vote. So extra query to get them is not necessary.

But if you use projects, the `.Include` calls are not necessary (in fact they are even ignored, when you reference navigation properties in the projection).

```
// Assuming your navigation property is called VoteMedia
await _context.Votes.
    .Include(vote => vote.VoteMedia)
    ...
    .Select( vote => new
    {
        Id = vote.Id,
        VoteQuestions = vote.VoteQuestions,

        // here you reference to VoteMedia from your Model
        // EF Core recognize that and will load VoteMedia too.
        //
        // When using _context.VoteMedias.Where(...), EF won't do that
        // because you directly call into the context
        VoteImages = vote.VoteMedias.Where(m => m.VoteId == vote.Id)
            .Select(k => k.MediaUrl.ToString()),

        // Same here
        Options = vote.VoteOptions.Where(m => m.VoteId == vote.Id).Select( ques => ... );
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it works this way? According to my testing it generates one join instead of multiple queries.

Comment: Yes, it will create one (or more joins) and fetch the data with a single query. EF Core may decide to split that into multiple queries if it can't find a way to make it in a single query. But it will try to do that in as less queries as possible. But one query with multiple joins is much faster than 3000 single queries. But if the filters are correct it will only fetch the data required and map it correctly to the models

Comment: Since you are using the navigation properties to access  VoteMedias and VoteOptions you can safely remove the `Where(m => m.VoteId == vote.id)` from your code.

Comment: Also if you are doing filtering on non-foreign/non-primary keys, make sure to put an [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes) on that column to speed up joins and queries

Comment: I don't think OP is doing something terrible wrong. Yes, there are some redundant `Where` filters, but the main issue is EF Core query translation / materialization leading to N + 1 queries rather than few queries similar to `Include`. There must be an issue in their tracker.

Comment: @IvanStoev: The OP is calling `_context` within the projection (that's causing the N+1), and not using the navigation properties of the model passed. EF Core can't recognize this constellation and optimize it. In order for the queries to be reduced, one must do the projection operation on the model passed to `.Select(vote => ...)` (here `vote`).

Comment: @Tseng Using `_context` `DbSets` inside LINQ to Entities queries should not generate N + 1 queries. At least it doesn't in EF6. That's why IMO this is current EF Core bug.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Well EF Core is a complete rewrite, don't expect it to work in the same way. EF Core already behaves differently (by design) in the way it tracks entities changes. See Julie Lermans blog post on the [change tracking behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt767693.aspx)

Comment: @Tseng I know. Still this behavior is definitely not "by design". See [**Reduce n + 1 queries**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9282) item in their [**Roadmap**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap)